# Como usar una sesión en una vista con adonisJS?

Tags: nodejs

Necesito usar la sesión que guardo, cuando el usuario se logea, para generarle el panel administrativo (menu) de manera dinámica en base a sus roles, Como puedo obtener esa sesión? Estoy intentando esto

```
{% set Session = use('Adonis/Src/Session') %} {% yield views = Session.get('views') %}
```

Pero obtengo este error: Error: Unable to call Session["get"], which is undefined or falsey

Answer (score 0):

En Adonis tienes disponible el objeto `request` en los templates:

```
{% if request.session.role == 'admin' %}
  <!-- Menu de administrador aquí -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: El problema sigue presente en adonis 3.2 (Versión que utilizaba en ese momento), lo solucione usando `response.viewInstance;`